# tsconfig's path parameter and ESLint

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I've been setting up the `paths` option in my `tsconfig.json` file. So far everything works fine. I can run my tests, and I can execute the program as usual. My only problem is, that ESLint does not find the modules that are accessed with one of the paths defined in `tsconfig.json`.

Here are all of the files that are related to the problem:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*", "index.ts"]
}
```

tsconfig.eslint.json:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*", "index.ts", ".eslintrc.js"]
}
```

.eslintrc.js:

```js
{
    root: true,
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es6: true,
        node: true
    },
    extends: ['plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: ['tsconfig.eslint.json'],
        sourceType: 'module'
    },
    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {}
        }
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import', 'prefer-arrow'],
    rules: {...}
}
```

Am am using the package [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript).

Now, if I try to import the file './src/test.ts' into './index.ts' with the path '@/test', then ESLint will not be able to resolve that import (although TypeScript resolves it just fine).

I've mostly copied my current solution from [here](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1485), because I thought the person who asked that problem had the same problem that I had, but my setup still does not work.

I am in an NodeJS environment by the way.

EDIT:
I've also tried using the package [eslint-import-resolver-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-alias). This only helped partially. I could get rid of the 'import/no-unresolved' errors, but whenever I call an imported function, I get '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call' because apparently, ESLint does not find the types for the imported files and thusly gives everything the type `any`.

Answer (score 10):

For those using Angular and `.eslintrc.json`, I use this (notice the 2 stars in "Project"

```
        "parserOptions": {
            "project": ["**/tsconfig.json"],
            "createDefaultProgram": true
        },
```

Comment: This is finally what worked for me. Putting in a tsconfigRootDir entry worked for me in VsCode but failed when I ran "ng lint". Taking out tsconfigRootDir worked for me when I ran "ng lint" but failed in VsCode (errors in every .ts file). But adding the "**/" made it work in both places.

Comment: That did the trick for me, too, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Could you try adding the `tsconfigRootDir` to your `.eslintrc.js`? It has worked for me.

```
parserOptions: {
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add eslint plugin https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#typescript

there under the `extends` you can specify option for typescript

```
extends:
  - plugin:import/typescript
```

it should do the trick